# Previous helpful flags do not count as an 'other action' in the First Questions review queue

Tags: bug, review, flags

When reviewing First Questions, if you've already raised a flag on the question before the review, this counts as an action and you can select 'Other action', which will result in a 'Reviewed' review task result.

However, if that flag has been marked helpful (e.g. a close flag, when another user voted to close the question too) before you open the review item, it is *not* counted as an action. I'm not sure if this is a bug which has been inherited from the retired First Posts queue, or that this is something new. It's worth checking whether First Answers has this problem as well.

Comment: I was under the impression that questions on which one has *already* raised a flag should not be presented to one in review queues. Or is that only for LQA? Or maybe your diamond changes things?

Comment: @AdrianMole I thought so too; this happened to me on MathOverflow so no diamond tricks involved.

Comment: Ha. I thought there was only one site left where you don't have a diamond. xD